# is there any way to change the metadata of a file without COPYING (not reencoding!) in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video

as title. I've seen an absolute ton of posts that discuss changing metadata without **reencoding**, but I'm trying to mass output files to reset their rotation values. Is there any way to do this without needing to copy bits over to another file; instead just changing the file's metadata?

I've tried the following:

`ffmpeg -i 0003.MP4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 0003_fixed.MP4`

and while this *mostly* works for my use case, I'm trying to perform this a lot faster than re-copying an entire file.

additionally, in comparing the output file of this fixed file vs the output file of a file I didn't have to rotate, there are a bit of differences in metadata somehow:

**unchanged file:**

```
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '0002.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Duration: 00:41:41.62, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 45201 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 45000 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 17:01:09:16
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : GoPro AVC
      timecode        : 17:01:09:16
```

**changed file:**

```
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '0003_fixed.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:35:23.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 45201 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 45000 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : GoPro AVC
      timecode        : 17:43:43:04
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : GoPro AVC
      timecode        : 17:43:43:04
```

notice here that it seems to remove the `encoder: GoPro AVC encoder` piece of metadata. could someone give a way for me to use this utility in a way that doesn't remove any other metadata except for the rotation flag, and also doesn't require an entire copy (i.e. does it inplace)? thanks y'all!

I'm hoping to find a solution to this that

Comment: ffmpeg doesn't edit anything inplace.  That said, in theory, for a MP4, if the rotation data structure (displaymatrix) is already in place then it's a matter of flipping some bits using a hex editor after locating it. Won't be straightforward as you have to make sure you don't mangle the data. However, based on unchanged file readout, I don't see the displaymatrix present.

Comment: this makes sense! thank you, and sorry for the very late reply! in that case, if I can't do it inplace, I was wondering if I could loop it in with another request.

currently, I have a script to concatenate several files together into a combined file (they're chaptered, so I'm trying to mix them together). this is done in python as:
`ffmpeg.input('F:\gopro_chaptering\merge_list.txt', format='concat', safe=False).output(i, c='copy').run()`.

is there any way to also modify the metadata of this final file to reset rotation?

Comment: I could just make another post, but this does seem like a followup request

Comment: i'm guessing you didn't manage this?